# TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Tags: python

I am trying to translate file name without number. I am getting following error:

```
>>> file ="1abc89.jpg"
>>> os.rename(file,file.translate(None,"0123456789"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

I tried searching few threads, but am not able to get the point.

Comment: Can you please provide full code?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python

import os

path = os.getcwd()
file_list = os.listdir(path)
print "without change %s",file_list
os.chdir(path)
for i in file_list:
    print ""+i
    after_change = os.rename(i, i.translate(None,"0123456789"))

Comment: Is there an error, when you're running `file.translate(None,"0123456789")` all by itself?

Comment: Provide Python version and a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3.4:

```
>>> import os
>>> name = '1abc89.jpg'
>>> name.translate(str.maketrans('','','0123456789'))
'abc.jpg'
>>> os.rename(name,name.translate(str.maketrans('','','0123456789')))
```

Python 2.7:

```
>>> import os
>>> name = '1abc89.jpg'
>>> name.translate(None,'0123456789')
'abc.jpg'
>>> os.rename(name,name.translate(None,'0123456789'))
```

References:

- Python 2.7: [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate)
- Python 3.4: [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans)  [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate)

Comment: For 3.x, using ordinal lookups is generally considered "better practice", eg: `name.translate({ord(k): None for k in '0123456789'})`

Comment: That's exactly what maketrans() generates.

Comment: Indeed - but if you later find the need to do other translations, then the mapping is easier to grok than the `str.maketrans('', '', other)` stuff... just my opinion anyway

Comment: not working 
>>> name = '1abc89.jpg'
>>> name.translate(None,'0123456789')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

versionPython 2.4.3 (#1, Oct  1 2006, 17:59:36)

Comment: @Rajesh hang on - you're using Python 2.4.3 ? It's 2015 now, you know? :p

Comment: Which is why I asked for Python version...I couldn't get his error message with either version.

Comment: FYI, @Rajesh, I used 2.7 and 3.4.

Comment: @Mark guess you'd better throw in `re.sub('\d+', '', name)` then... or a `..join(ch for ch in name if not ch.isdigit())` or something

Comment: And the `TypeError: expected a character buffer object` was reworded to `TypeError: expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object` in Python 3.

Comment: it works with python 3.x.  thanks a lot Mark. but am not sure why this one is not working with python 2.4 . have to check .... thanks guys...