# Python translate function not working

Tags: python, translate

I have this following simple function which I try to replace any numeric values of a file name inside a given folder. This is what I have so far

```
import os

def decode_message():

    #this is stage one
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\TestFolder");
    #this is stage two
    print(file_list);
    os.chdir(r"C:\TestFolder")
    saved_path = os.getcwd();
    print("Current Working Directory : "+saved_path)
    for file_name in file_list:
            print("Old File Name : "+file_name);
            os.rename(file_name,file_name.translate(None,"0123456789"))
decode_message()
```

This is working up to the point where I can list the file names as shown below

[image]

But once i use the translate option it gives the following error

[image]

Can Anyone help?

Comment: your script is called `prank.py`, this is not a prank, is it? :-)

Comment: No its not. its just a name i given

Comment: This must be a problem with Unicode characters in filenames. Split your files in two halfs. Run script on both. Does the error happen only in one of the halfs? If yes, continue until you notice the specific file that causes this problem.

Comment: I removed all but one still have the same issue.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1: Update your python version**: You're on python 2.4 which is about 12 years old by now. If you update to Python 2.7 your `translate` would work. I don't have a python 2.4 version available, nor can I find the documentation. Also: have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743314/typeerror-expected-a-character-buffer-object) and the answers. It is exactly the same question

**Solution 2: Replace the numeric character with something else**

e.g.

```
import re
os.rename(file_name, re.sub('\d+', '', file_name))
```

or

```
file_name2 = "".join(ch for ch in file_name if not ch.isdigit())
os.rename(file_name, file_name2)
```

Comment: I've updated the version and it worked. I was using python 2.7 and somehow its been overwritten by 2.5 so once i installed 2.7 its working. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if you're looking at only files that begin with a digit. However some files begin with `.`, like the `.DS_Store` file, and your program is getting stuck there as it not taking into consideration any file that does not begin with a digit.

Comment: I've Deleted that file `.DS_Store` still give the same error

Comment: it has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

file_name.translate(None,"0123456789")

You can`t give None as translation table.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm

Comment: You can, in Python 2, which he is using